# Clinton's “wonky”

Tags: etymology, american-english, slang, colloquialisms

Until today I would have said that *wonky* means to be unstable, a word similar to *wobbly*. Any piece of furniture on legs can be wonky, it usually means one of the legs is slighter shorter than the others, but you can even have a wonky computer or TV set.

However, today I learnt that American candidates can be *wonky* too.

[image]

01.45 [BBC News](http://www.bbc.com/news/election-us-2016-36911157)

> Journalist: What is the real Hillary Clinton like?
>   Marjorie Margolies: **She's wonky**. She presents as if she knows the issues [...] that makes some people uncomfortable, particularly because they're not comfortable with wonky women.

What has happened to *wonky*?! When did *wonky* mean smart and policy-focused? Is this just an American English expression? Do Australians, Canadians have *wonky* women too?

Comment: Interesting, though dictionaries seem to disagree with the BBC: https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/wonky

Comment: I'm convinced 'wonky' is just how the media refers to Democratic candidates

Comment: For word wonks: *[What do “wonk” as against performer and “Wonking out” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85704)* and *[What does “Wonk gap” mean in brief?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126146)*

Comment: @jcast It's non-partisan. In 2012, it was a favored moniker for Paul Ryan, the Republican current Speaker of the House.

Comment: I had never understood "wonky" as anything other than what you described as your understanding of the word, and I'm an American...

Comment: As a Canadian, I've never heard wonky used to mean studious.  I've only seen it in American journalism.  "Unstable" is the synonym that comes to my mind.  So this journalistic use seems to me to have a disparaging sense.

Comment: I don't often use the term "policy wonk" (it's more common in the US than Canada), but if I were going to use it in an adjective form, I would say "wonkish" rather than "wonky", to avoid the connotation the questioner described.

Comment: Is that quoted in its entirety?  Because the passage you quoted (presumably from the video, verbatim) doesn't make any sense.  Is there something missing where you put the ellipses? (...)

Comment: @RobertHarvey  I should have added the square brackets, oops! The ellipsis is only substituting redundant words. You can watch the  video in its entirety in the link. The actual interview begins at 01.45.

Comment: I think the BBC  folks (who apparently are [following Hillary's lead](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonky?fb_comment_id=10150112897996365_10153825920941365)) just [don't understand what the word "wonky" means](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTRKCXC0JFg).

Comment: "*Q. What do you call a donkey with one leg shorter than the rest? A. A wonky donkey*".  This BrE joke takes on extra meaning considering the DNC mascot.

Comment: "wonky" and "geeky" mean almost the same thing; and note that they come from "wonk" and "geek" respectively.

Comment: I generally hear "wonky" used to describe something that raises suspicion but hasn't yet proven that said suspicion is due. For example, your "wonky" table raises suspicion that it might collapse, but it hasn't... yet. Reading the quote in your example that way gives it an entirely different meaning, but depending on what was omitted, it could be fitting.

Comment: "Off-center" (from the link @Helmar provided above) is the only possible *positive* reading I can see of this term.

Comment: there is a increase at google search for "wonky" since 2004: [https://www.google.de/trends/explore?date=all&q=wonky](https://www.google.de/trends/explore?date=all&q=wonky)

Answer (score 32):

It derives from the OED sense 4 of the word ***wonk***.

It is often used of government officials with a very narrow, but deep field of expertise. For example someone within the Foreign Office, or State Department with a profound knowledge of China, and everything Chinese might be described as a *China wonk*.

> 4. U.S. A disparaging term for a studious or hard-working person.
>
> 1962   Sports Illustr. 17 Dec. 21   A wonk, sometimes called a
>   ‘turkey’ or a ‘lunch’, roughly corresponds to the ‘meatball’ of a
>   decade ago.
>
> 1970   E. Segal Love Story 32   Who could Jenny be talking to that was
>   worth appropriating moments set aside for a date with me? Some musical
>   wonk?
>
> 1980   N.Y. Times Mag. 20 July 8   At Harvard the excessively studious
>   student is derided as a ‘wonk’, which Amy Berman, Harvard '79,
>   fancifully suggests may be ‘know’ spelled backward. (In British slang,
>   ‘wonky’ means ‘unsteady’.)

Comment: "... _may be_ 'know' spelled backward"?  I always assumed that's precisely what it was since it then aligns with the idiom "[to know something backward and forward](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/know-something-backward-and-forward)."

Comment: @DylanCristy Very interesting. The OED have not, so far, caught up with this - it would appear.

Comment: It is quite rare to hear "a wonk" described in a positive manner as "wonky". Even in America, "wonky" is commonly used as a synonym for "weird" or "unstable", hence why calling someone "a wonk" is often considered disparaging. It's like calling someone "a nerd". At best, it is not a compliment. Marjorie Margolies' [mis]use of the term seems to be either an accident or an attempt to redefine the word (a common political tactic). Whether inadvertent or intentional, this is a good example of [semantic change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change).

Comment: @gfullam I've never thought of the term *policy wonk*, when applied to the likes of Treasury, or Central Bank officials as particularly disparaging. I would have put it as neutral, mid-way between a complement and an insult.

Comment: @gfullam I suppose it comes down to the audience. I rather like being called a *wonk* or a *nerd*, but then, I do live inside the Beltway.

Comment: @choster I think this may be an example of a disparaging term that has been appropriated by people to whom it was originally implied, reversing the disparaging sense in the new usage.

Comment: @DavidK Yes! That's what I was attempting to convey with my clumsy and wordy preface to referencing semantic change.

Comment: @choster I don't believe a *wonk* is the same thing as a *nerd*. My understanding is that *wonks* are central to an organisation's operations, possessing an in-depth grasp of detail.

Comment: @WS2 A *wonk* may very well be those things, but not by necessity. To call someone a *wonk* is to say "you are slightly weird because you posses such an *uncommon* in-depth grasp of detail that it makes you different and therefore worthy of jovial (yet perhaps disparaging) recognition." The word can be taken as disparaging even endearing, but it's not merely neutral.

Comment: @gfullam But it's not nearly as strong as *nerd*.

Comment: As someone who lives in DC, I agree with @choster that it can very much be a positive term here. American University even has an entire brand campaign around it: [American University WONK Brand Campaign](https://www.american.edu/ucm/work/know-wonk.cfm)

Answer (score 18):

According to the ***[Gramnarist](http://grammarist.com/words/wonkish-wonky/)***, the different meanings of wonky are used in all English dialects. The  "smart, policy-focused" connotation appears to be from the AmE slang term ***wonk*** (a derogatory term for a studious person) of  the late 20th century:

> ***The adjective wonky has two unrelated senses that are both used throughout the English-speaking world.***
>
> ***1)*** - ***Its older and more commonly used definition is unstable, defective, unreliable, or wobbly***. For instance, a bad knee or a table with loose fittings might be called wonky, ***as might a person who behaves unpredictably***
>
> ***2)*** -  ***The word’s second sense is studiously concerned with minutiae***. It connotes the kind of expertise that only a long-time insider within a given field can have, and ***it often comes up in politics, where a wonky person is one who is immersed in the details of policy***.
>
> - Wonky in its second sense comes from the slightly older noun wonk, which emerged in the United States in the late 20th century as slang for a studious person concerned with minutiae. Wonk‘s origins are not known, however. Wonky in the first sense came about in the early 20th century, is British in origin, and has no corresponding noun, so it doesn’t appear that the two senses of wonky share a common origin.

As suggested by @Mitch, a related expression that has been around from the ['80s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=policy%20wonk%2C%20he%20is%20wonky&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpolicy%20wonk%3B%2Cc0) is ***[policy wonk](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/policy-wonk)***:

> - an expert in administration or government, esp. one overly concerned with policy details. *Usage Note*: slang.

Comment: Interesting, I've never encountered that second definition before.  See also https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/policy_wonk  That grammarist article also refers to the alternative adjective ***wonkish***, eg http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wonkish

Comment: The second meaning has been used commonly for quite a while (~20 years) in the media, especially re: 'policy wonk'.

Comment: If you saw the old American teen-age movie "Revenge of the Nerds", the main nerd characters would now be called wonks.

Answer (score 13):

In [A Political Theory of Geeks and Wonks](https://mises.org/library/political-theory-geeks-and-wonks), Jeffrey Tucker characterized wonks as

> Political wonks are fascinated by process. They love the game. They
>   get as much satisfaction from observing as changing. They want to be
>   players above all else. Ideals bore them. History is mere data.
>   Intellectuals seem irrelevant. What matters to the wonk are the hard
>   realities of the ongoing political struggle. They defer to title and
>   rank. They thrive on meetings, small victories, administrative
>   details, and gossip about these matters. Knowing who is who and what
>   is what is the very pith of life.

In contrast and often opposition are the geeks.

> In contrast to this are the policy geeks. They are no less fascinated
>   by detail but are drawn to ideals. Observation alone bores them. They
>   are drawn to the prospect of change. They don't want to be players as
>   such; they question the very rules of the game and want to change
>   them. They are happy to make a difference in the ideological
>   infrastructure, whether big or small. They tend to work alone and
>   totally disregard caste distinctions. They are interested not in the
>   surface area but what's underneath, not the veneer but the wood.  In
>   software terms, they are forever looking forward to the next build.
>   They are risk takers, so they prefer to debug after the system is
>   live.

The author places a few historical figures into these buckets.

> - Caesar: Wonk
> - Brutus: Geek
> - Hamilton: Wonk
> - Jefferson: Geek
> - Cheney: Wonk
> - Paul: Geek

Answer (score 10):

Grant Barrett, *The Oxford Dictionary of American Political Slang* (2004) has this entry for *wonk*:

> **wonk** *n.* an expert on intricate policies; (broadly) a studious or hardworking person. Also **policy wonk**. [Cited examples omitted.]

As presented here, *wonk* is clearly not a pejorative term. However, the limits of *wonk* as a positive notion are suggested by the same dictionary's entry for *wonkism*:

> **wonkism** *n.* excessively deep knowledge of policies; the habits or character of a WONK. [Cited examples omitted.]

The implicit criticism embedded in the term *wonkism* would thus appear to be along the lines of "how could anyone care that much about something that boring?" This criticism is probably familiar to the many people at this site who are, in effect, grammar and usage wonks.

William Safire, *Safire's Political Dictionary* (2008) has this take on the term *policy wonk*:

> **policy wonk** A grimly serious scholar of the tedious side of public affairs; stiff staffer steeped in study.
>
> In the 1992 election, both Bill Clinton and Al Gore were known to delight in the minutiae of program development, causing Meg Greenfield of *Newsweek* to refer to them as "tough., ambitious, leadership-minded policy wonks."
>
> *Wonk* is nautical slang for "cadet," but there is no clear relation between the terms. *Sports Illustrated* in 1962 wrote: "A wonk, sometimes called a 'turkey' or a 'lunch,' roughly corresponds to the 'meatball' of a decade ago." The suggestion that wonk may be "*know* spelled backward" may be dismissed as folk etymology.
>
> In the 1984 Presidential election Sidney Blumenthal of *The New Republic* used the academic slang politically, referring to Walter Mondale's "thralldom to the policy wonks an wise men of the Washington establishment." In 2007 Hillary Clinton, presenting her concerns about healthcare costs to an audience of medical professionals at George Washington University, having been described in the local media as "a battle-scarred participant in the 1993 health-care overhaul failure," made a self-deprecating comment about not getting "overly wonky," using the adjective derived in 1978 from the noun.

It thus appears that hostility to expertise has long (at least since 1984) been embedded in the negative use of "policy wonk," "wonkism," and "wonky" in a political context. Nevertheless, there is also a hint of grudging admiration in the term "policy wonk," implying the same kind of uneasy respect that mainstream law students have for fellow students who plan to specialize in tax law.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Law Notes](https://books.google.com/books?id=yyAOAQAAMAAJ&q=%22technical%20term%20of%20law.%20One%20of%20the%20judges%20at%20the%20Old%20Bailey%20%22&dq=%22technical%20term%20of%20law.%20One%20of%20the%20judges%20at%20the%20Old%20Bailey%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin1c3Qu4rRAhUM4iYKHdQHBYcQ6AEIGjAA) Volume 50 (1931) and well as [The Irish Law Times and Solicitors' Journal](https://books.google.com/books?id=L4QvAQAAIAAJ&q=%22technical%20term%20of%20law.%20One%20of%20the%20judges%20at%20the%20Old%20Bailey%20%22&dq=%22technical%20term%20of%20law.%20One%20of%20the%20judges%20at%20the%20Old%20Bailey%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin1c3Qu4rRAhUM4iYKHdQHBYcQ6AEIHzAB), Volume 65 (1931):

> "Wonky" takes its place in the English language as a technical term of law. One of the judges at the Old Bailey last month said: "I think 'wonky' means that you are wrong in your head, but your legs are all right." This definition may be questioned: some hold the opinion that it means the reverse. However, the Editor of "Stroud's Judicial Dictionary " must take care that " wonky " appears in the next edition. Someone has suggested that it is to be found in one of Shakespeare's plays. Can any reader help?

"Wonk" has a different meaning.

According to [Harvard Alumni Bulletin](https://books.google.com/books?id=y1TnAAAAMAAJ&q=%22wonk+in+particular,+the+lampoon%22&dq=%22wonk+in+particular,+the+lampoon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK8ovMvYvRAhWl8oMKHfO5BMUQ6AEIHDAA) 1957:

> ...generally the *Lampoon* has of late seemed to many rather tame. But in the month of March Lampy tolled in a new slate of officers "with an ecstatic yank on the bell cord" and produced the widely discussed "Wonk Number". Before launching into an attack on the wonk in general and the Harvard wonk in particular, the *Lampoon* defined its terms. " 'It's a difference in attitude,' muttered the Jester. . . . 'They *don't have my values*! They don't respect The Old Order! Instead of vests, they adorn themselves with slide rules; with slide rules; they dress as if they'd bought their clothes blindfolded at a Polish rummage sale. They disgust me!'" While the March edition made a faint attempt to satirize the values of The Old Order, as a "Wonk Number" it was almost exclusively dedicated to an attack on the "unsuitable" elements in Harvard today.